# Is this sentence a positive or negative statement?

Tags: sentence-structure, legal-terminology

I'm signing a contract about taking an apartment. There is a list that I have to accept and sign. So I am expecting all the items in this list to be positive things about my tenancy, because I will sign and state that I accept them. However the 1st item looks like a negative statement to me. Can you check please, what does the 1st item here mean? Doesn't it mean something like "An eviction lawsuit is ongoing about my flat"? So this is a bad thing right? While all the other items justify that I'm a trustworthy tenant, why would this item be against me?

- Über die Räumung meiner/unserer Wohnung war/ist ein Räumungsrechtsstreit anhängig.
- Ich/wir habe(n) in den letzten 3 Jahren weder eine eidesstattliche Versicherung abgegeben, noch erging ein Haftbefehl, noch ist ein solches Verfahren anhängig.
- Über mein/unser Vermögen wurde in den letzten 5 Jahren kein Insolvenzverfahren eröffnet bzw. die Eröffnung mangels Masse abgewiesen. Solche Verfahren sind derzeit auch nicht anhängig.
- Ich/wir bin/sind in der Lage, eine Mietsicherheit von 3 Monatsmieten zu leisten und die geforderte Miete laufend zu zahlen.

I've translated this from many places and still don't get what it exactly means, can you help me with this 1st item please? Thanks!

I think that the sentence should have **kein Räumungsrechtsstreit** instead of **ein Räumungsrechtsstreit**, so that it would mean something positive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with your assessment and doubts. The translation is:

> An eviction lawsuit was/is pending regarding the eviction from my/our apartment.

I'm afraid you'll have to discuss that with the landlord. It's most probably a mistake, and they either need to correct and re-print the declaration, or you could both sign the correction to "kein".